# Xilinx. xst:737 error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have a project where i use a memory(24x12), the memory is written when okk internal signal takes value 4, when i am generating the programming file i get a xst 737 error for every bit in my memory.

Can someone help me fix those warrnings?

partial code for the main architecture:

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_logic_1164.all;
 use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity Termostat is
port (set: in std_logic;                         -- intrare folosita 
                                       pentru intrarea in modul de setare
      s: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);        -- intrare pentru a alege 
                                        modul de setare -> 3 stari de setare 
      clk: in std_logic;                         -- intrare de clock de pe 
                                            placa 
      plus, minus: in std_logic;                 -- butoane pentru setarea 
                                        manuala a componentelor
      ok: in std_logic;                          
      mode: out std_logic;                       -- iesire care indica daca 
                                       incalzirea este pornita sau nu
      anod:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);     -- iesire pentru afisorul 7-segmente 
      display:out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)); -- iesire pentru afisorul 7-segmente cu cifra de afisat
    end Termostat;


architecture TERM of Termostat is

component Ceas is
port (clk, set, plus, ok, minus: in std_logic; 
      ora: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
      min: out std_logic_vector (5 downto 0)); 
end component Ceas;  

component debounce is
port (buton:in std_logic;
      clk: in std_logic;
      buton_out: out std_logic);
end component debounce; 

component US is
port (temp, t_min, t_max:in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
      clk, set:in std_logic; 
      puls, mode:out std_logic);
end component US; 

component Termistor is
port (set, minus, plus, clk:in std_logic; 
      temp_mod, puls:in std_logic;
      temp:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));
end component Termistor;     

component UMDT is
port (ora:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); set, plus, minus, ok, clk:in std_logic; 
temp_min, temp_max:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
ora1, ora2:out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
t_min_set, t_max_set:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));
end component UMDT;

component bcd5 is 
port (in_vect:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); out_vect:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component bcd5;      

component bcd6 is 
port (in_vect:in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0); out_vect:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component bcd6; 

component afisor is
port (af:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); clk:in std_logic;
display:out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); anod:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component afisor;


signal ora: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others =>'0');         -- ora indicata de ceas
signal ora1, ora2: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others =>'0');  -- semanale utiliate la setarea intervalelor de temp. pe ore dela ora1 la ora2
signal min: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others =>'0');         -- min indicate de ceas 
signal temp: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others =>'0');        -- temp indicata de termistor
signal t_min, t_max: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others =>'0');-- temp minima si maxima corescunzatoare pt ora actuala de la UMDT la US
signal t_max_set, t_min_set: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others =>'0');-- temp minima si maxima utilizate la setarea intervalelor de temp pe ore
signal plus_deb, ok_deb, minus_deb: std_logic :='0';                -- iesirile de la debouncerele pentru butoane
signal t_mode: std_logic :='0';                                     -- modul de functionare al incalziri transmis de la US la termistor
signal puls: std_logic :='0';                                       -- semnal de clock trasmis de la US la termistor cu perioada 3 sec
signal com0, com1, com2, com3: std_logic :='0';                     -- semnalele de comanda
signal af_sig: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0):= (others =>'0');     -- semnalul de afisat transmis la afisor
signal ora_bcd, ora1_bcd, ora2_bcd, temp_bcd, min_bcd, t_min_bcd, t_max_bcd: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others =>'0'); 
                                  -- iesirile transformate in bcd ale valorilor de afisat
begin           

com0<='1' when (set='0' or (s(1)='0' and s(0)='0')) else '0';
com1<='1' when (set='1' and s(0)='1' and s(1)='0') else '0';
com2<='1' when (set='1' and s(0)='0' and s(1)='1') else '0';
com3<='1' when (set='1' and s(0)='1' and s(1)='1') else '0';

deb1: debounce port map (buton =>plus, clk =>clk, buton_out =>plus_deb);
deb2: debounce port map (buton =>minus, clk =>clk, buton_out =>minus_deb);
deb3: debounce port map (buton =>ok, clk =>clk, buton_out =>ok_deb);  


c1: Ceas port map (set =>com2, clk =>clk, min =>min, minus =>minus_deb, plus =>plus_deb, ok =>ok_deb, ora =>ora); 
c2: US port map (temp =>temp, t_min =>t_min, t_max =>t_max, clk =>clk, puls =>puls, mode =>t_mode, set =>com0);
c3: Termistor port map (set =>com1, plus =>plus_deb, minus =>minus_deb, clk =>clk, temp_mod =>t_mode, puls =>puls, temp =>temp);
c4: UMDT port map (set =>com3, plus =>plus_deb, ok =>ok_deb, minus =>minus_deb, clk =>clk, ora =>ora, temp_min =>t_min,
                    temp_max =>t_max, t_min_set =>t_min_set, t_max_set =>t_max_set, ora1 =>ora1, ora2 =>ora2);
end architecture;
```

and the component that gives the errors:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;       


entity UMDT is
port (ora:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);              -- ora actuala
set:in std_logic;                                       -- intrare de set pt intervale de temp
plus, minus, ok:in std_logic;                           -- butoanele + ,- si ok
clk:in std_logic;                                       -- clock de la placa
temp_min, temp_max:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);    -- temp minima si temp maxima corestunzatoare pt ora actuala
ora1, ora2:out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);            -- orele din modul set de afisat
t_min_set, t_max_set:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)); -- temperaturile din modul set de afisat
end UMDT;


architecture struct of UMDT is              
constant timer:integer :=20;--_000_000;             -- 5 cresteri pe secunda in modul set
type lin is array(11 downto 0) of std_logic;
type memory is array(0 to 23) of lin; 
signal mem: memory :=(others => "010100010001");    -- memoria utilizata pt retinerea intervalelor de temp, tmax si tmin initial 20 respectiv 17 
signal o1, o2: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');                -- semanle utilizate pt setarea intervalelor orare
signal t_min, t_max, t1, t2: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');  -- semanle utilizate pt setarea intervalelor temperaturilor, 
temperaturile de iesire t_min si t_max acutale
signal mem_line, mem_ora: lin := (others =>'0');
signal okk: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= "000";                              -- semnal de selectie
signal oo1, oo2, oo:integer range 0 to 23 :=0;                                 -- valoare intreaga a semnalelor o1, o2 si ora
signal guard: std_logic := '0';                                                -- utilizata pt scrierea in memorie
signal perioada: std_logic_vector (23 downto 0) := (others =>'0');             -- utilizat pt cresterea de 5 ori intr o secunda in modul set
begin                                        

okay: process (ok)
begin
    if ok='1' then
        okk<=okk+1; 
    end if;
    if okk=4 then 
        okk<="000";
    end if;
end process okay;

sett: process (okk, set, plus, minus, clk, o1, o2, t_min, t_max)
begin  
    if clk='1' and clk'event then
        if set='1' then 
            perioada<=perioada+1;
            if plus='1' then
                if perioada>=timer then
                    perioada<=(others =>'0');
                    case okk is
                        when "000" => 
                            o1<=o1+1;
                            if o1=23 then
                                o1<="00000";
                            end if;
                        when "001" =>
                            o2<=o2+1;
                            if o2=23 then
                                o2<="00000";
                            end if;
                        when "010" =>
                            t_min<=t_min+1;
                        when "011" =>
                            t_max<=t_max+1;   
                        when others => null;
                    end case;
                end if;
            end if;

            if minus='1' then 
                if perioada=timer then
                    perioada<=perioada+1;
                    case okk is
                        when "000" => 
                            o1<=o1-1;
                            if o1=23 then
                                o1<="10111";
                            end if;
                        when "001" =>
                            o2<=o2-1;
                            if o2=0 then
                                o2<="10111";
                            end if;
                        when "010" =>
                            t_min<=t_min-1;
                        when "011" =>
                            t_max<=t_max-1;
                        when others => null;
                    end case;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process sett;


oo1<=conv_integer(o1);
oo2<=conv_integer(o2); 
ora1<=o1;
ora2<=o2;    
t_min_set<=t_min;
t_max_set<=t_max;

 mem_line(11)<= t_max(5);  
 mem_line(10)<= t_max(4); 
 mem_line(9)<= t_max(3);
 mem_line(8)<= t_max(2); 
 mem_line(7)<= t_max(1);  
 mem_line(6)<= t_max(0); 
 mem_line(5)<= t_min(5); 
 mem_line(4)<= t_min(4); 
 mem_line(3)<= t_min(3); 
 mem_line(2)<= t_min(2); 
 mem_line(1)<= t_min(1);  
 mem_line(0)<= t_min(0);  

 guard<= '1' when (okk=4) else '0';
 mem(0)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and ((oo1=0) or ((oo1>oo2) and (0<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2)) else mem(0);
 mem(1)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=1) and (1<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (1<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(2)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=2) and (2<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (2<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(3)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=3) and (3<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (3<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(4)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=4) and (4<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (4<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(5)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=5) and (5<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (5<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(6)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=6) and (6<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (6<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(7)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=7) and (7<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (7<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(8)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=8) and (8<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (8<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(9)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=9) and (9<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (9<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(10)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=10) and (10<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (10<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(11)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=11) and (11<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (11<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(12)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=12) and (12<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (12<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(13)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=13) and (13<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (13<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(14)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=14) and (14<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (14<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(15)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=15) and (15<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (15<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(16)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=16) and (16<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (16<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(17)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=17) and (17<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (17<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(18)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=18) and (18<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (18<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(19)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=19) and (19<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (19<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(20)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=20) and (20<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (20<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));  
 mem(21)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=21) and (21<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (21<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(22)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=22) and (22<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (22<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
 mem(23)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=23) and (23<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (23<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));

 oo<=conv_integer(ora);
 mem_ora<=mem(oo);
 t1(5)<=mem_ora(11);
 t1(4)<=mem_ora(10);
 t1(3)<=mem_ora(9);
 t1(2)<=mem_ora(8);
 t1(1)<=mem_ora(7);
 t1(0)<=mem_ora(6);
 t2(5)<=mem_ora(5);
 t2(4)<=mem_ora(4);
 t2(3)<=mem_ora(3);
 t2(2)<=mem_ora(2);
 t2(1)<=mem_ora(1);
 t2(0)<=mem_ora(0);  

 temp_min<=t2;
 temp_max<=t1;
end architecture struct;
```

here are the errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA4ST.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cRkC.png)

the errors ar for each line in the memory.

You are right i didn't give explanations of what the component should do.

I want to implement my code on a nexys 4 fpga as a university project, the project is to describe a thermostat for an apartment, the thermostat need to have a digital clock and the ability to set hourly intervals of minimum and maximum temperature. this component(c4:UMDT) is where i have my memory for the temperature intervals for each of the 24 hours. the set of the intervals is given by this diagram uml we have o1, o2, t_min, t_max and the memory should be written betwenn hours o1 and o2 the minimum temperature is t_min and the maximum temperature is t_max

"plus", "minus" and "ok" are pushbutton inputs

Comment: Ok, you provided brief explanation about what your design should do, but my answer still seems to address you question about error. Check if it is useful, and write another question (or edit this one) if still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well... The error message is quite clear. You have incomplete when/else statement in almost all lines, where you assign something to memory. For example:

```
mem(1)<=mem_line when (guard='1') and (((oo1<=1) and (1<oo2)) or ((oo1>oo2) and (1<oo2)) or (oo1=oo2));
```

But you didn't provide any explanation of your design, so I can't tell if it is only wrong thing. I have a feeling, that this part should be done in some other way.

I will also point three more things:

- In process that is sensitive on clock edge, and does not have reset,
  you don't have to put to sensitivity list anything other than this
  clock.
- Try to avoid nested if statements. It leads to complicated
  logic.
- I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve in `okay` process, but you may need to add `okk` signal to sensitivity list.